# Defining Axis function in R

Tags: r, plot

When drawing axis for time series, we usually create the tick marks and add the axis separately. 
Since I have to plot many time series, I tried to write the following function :

Simple plot command

```
 set.seed(1)

 x <- as.ts(rnorm(1:150))

 plot <- plot(x, xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n")
```

Convert a set of commands from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13067012/date-format-for-plotting-x-axis-ticks-of-time-series-data) into a function

```
tt = seq(as.Date("1994-03-01"), by="months", length=150)

tsAxis <- function (tt) {

  ix <- seq_along(tt) # number of ticks 

  fmt <- "%b-%y"  # format of time 

  labs <- format(tt, fmt) # names or labels of dates

  axis(1, at = tt[ix], labels = labs[ix], 
       tcl = -0.7, cex.axis = 0.7, las = 2)
}
```

Then tsAxis(tt) must draw the axis but it doesnot and there is no error either. 
Even typing the commands separately does not plot the axis.

Any solutions?

Comment: In your `axis` function, try changing the parameter `at=tt[ix]` to `at=ix`. It seems R does not have the x-axis as dates form, but as integers.

Comment: Thanks. The axis are plotted now but raises another question. If we want only a third of the tick marks, `ix <- seq(1, length(tt), 3)`, then number of ticks and labels dont match.How to specify tick locations in that case?

Comment: Have you tried changing the line `ix <- seq_along(tt)` to `ix <- seq(1, length(tt), 3)` and running your code again? Seems to work for me. I have `axis(1, at = ix, labels = labs[ix], tcl = -0.7, cex.axis = 0.7, las = 2)` in the `tsAxis` function, which seems to work.

Comment: I tried that but it was giving error that at and label lengths differ. Its working now.

Comment: Would you like to post the comment as an answer or is this question trivial and to be deleted ?

Comment: I added my comments as an answer. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that R represents the x-axis with integers in this case (i.e. x=1 is the first event, x=2 is the second event, etc.). You can see this if you run the code:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- as.ts(rnorm(1:150))
# Take a look at the x-axis
plot <- plot(x)
```

We can modify your code to reflect this:

```
tt = seq(as.Date("1994-03-01"), by="months", length=150)
tsAxis <- function (tt) {
  ix <- seq_along(tt) # number of ticks 
  fmt <- "%b-%y"  # format of time 
  labs <- format(tt, fmt) # names or labels of dates
  # Change "at=tt[ix]" to "at=ix" here!
  axis(1, at = ix, labels = labs[ix], 
       tcl = -0.7, cex.axis = 0.7, las = 2)
}
```

Or if you want to plot every third tick mark, just change `ix <- seq_along(tt)` to `ix <- seq(1, length(tt), 3)` and it should work.