# Convert uneven Data Time [timestamps] series to regular time series : R

Tags: r, plot, timestamp, time-series

I have a data frame "gg", that looks like this:

```
> head(gg) 

           timestamps      value 
1 2017-04-25 16:52:00 -0.4120000 
2 2017-04-25 16:53:00 -0.4526667 
3 2017-04-25 16:54:00 -0.4586667 
4 2017-04-25 16:55:00 -0.4606667 
5 2017-04-25 16:56:00 -0.5053333 
6 2017-04-25 16:57:00 -0.5066667
```

I need to plot this as a Time series data to do forecasting. The steps are as follows:

1) `gg$timestamps <- as.POSIXct(gg$timestamps, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S")  #changing "Timestamps" column 'factor' to 'as.POSIXct'.`

2) `gg.ts <- xts(x=gg$value, order.by = gg$timestamps) #converting the dataframe to time series (Non Regular Time series)`

Now i want this `gg.ts`converted to regular time series to do forecasting like this ([Forecasting time series data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302261/forecasting-time-series-data))
But i don't know how to add the timestamp values series to `ts` function. When i tried it throws error :

```
>  gg.xts <- ts(gg.ts, frequency = '1', start = c(2017-04-25 16:52:00,171))
Error: unexpected numeric constant in "gg.xts <- ts(gg.ts, frequency = '1', start = c(2017-04-25 16"
```

I have my whole problem listed clearly here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627826/plotting-time-series-data-r-plotly-timestamp-values
please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Before everything, you'll need to make sure you have the right classes for the data. Make sure `gg$timestamps` is in POSIXct form or date form (whichever you preference is)

```
gg$timestamps<- as.POSIXct(strftime(gg$timestamps,format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

All you need to do is generate a new data.frame with the time series values based on your specific interval and then merge the new data.frame with `gg`

```
tstamp <- data.frame(x = seq(head(gg$timestamps,1),tail(gg$timestamps,1),by = "sec"))
res <-merge(tstamp, gg, by.x="x",by.y="timestamps",all.x = TRUE)
xts(res$value,order.by = res$x)     # you create your xts time series this way.
```

Note: you'll have some NA values in it, as your original timeseries was an irregular time series.

**Updated:**

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for the reply. But I want this time-stamp values to sit on my x axis using "ts" (for example: 'x =xts (res,order.by = res$x)  , x.ts = ts(x, freq=1, start=c(2017-04-25 16:48:00, 191))' . This x.ts throws error as i have mentioned above. The plot shows some random value on my graph in x axis. It is supposed to show the times-tamp value. Please refer to this  [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302261/forecasting-time-series-data)

Comment: The error you've got is because `start` takes in `numeric` as opposed to what you've entered.

Comment: Is there a way to add these timestamp values to 'start' ? becoz i want these timestamp values as my x axis scales to the forecast plot. I am getting some random values sitting on the x axis scale. hope you get my point here.